# Word for logical AND-or-OR-ness property

Tags: single-word-requests, logic

Suppose I have a set of criteria used in digital searches (such as "year is earlier than 1900", "name begins with S"). The user can choose whether to search for records matching ALL of their criteria, or ANY (at least one) of their criteria.

What noun describes the property that the user is choosing: the "AND-or-OR-ness" of the search? (Other logical operations could also be available in theory, like exclusive-OR.) I'm thinking there might be a technical term along the lines of "distributivity", though that's not the one.

Sample sentence: "The user's search didn't return any results because she picked the wrong ____: there are people beginning with S and birthdates before 1900, but not both."

Comment: Search criteria, as in your first sentence. If the selection is only one search item, you technically have only one search criterion, not criteria, but you can't win them all.

Comment: It's a [logic gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective) or [bitwise operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) I guess ?

Comment: Seems as though it's the **breadth** of the search, although it doesn't fit your  ___ well. Requiring **all** the search terms to be found is a **narrow** search, any of them is a **broad** search. "The user's search didn't return any results because it was too narrow."

Comment: What's wrong with *logical operation*? || how about *query*? *The user's search didn't return any results because she picked the wrong query . . .* For that matter, how could her query be wrong? It's not wrong because it yielded 0 results; why on earth would anyone ever want the set of everyone born before 1900 and everyone whose name begins with S?

Comment: It's always good to look at authoritative examples: the Library of Congress and British Library catalog advanced searches, Gale newspaper library, and JSTOR academic database all have controls with the options AND, OR, NOT, or similar, but none of them has any label at all to explain what you're choosing. Peering at the source suggests "combine", "bool operator" (as in boolean), "select" or "select operator", but my conclusion is that nobody really knows what to call this.

Comment: "Search combination operator" is a nontechnical way to describe it.

Comment: The terms *and* and *or* are grammatical ***conjunctions***, and logical ***connectives***.

Comment: I was hoping for a word for a property ("X-ness", "X-ity"), not a word for the individual thing (operator). But perhaps there is no such word.

Answer (score 2):

If your audience is technical, you can call one of them a logical operator.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Answer (score -1):

In English usage they are *conjunctions* that connect words or phrases.

> What are examples of conjunctions?
> Conjunction is a word that joins words, phrases, clauses or sentence. e.g. but, and, yet, or, because, nor, although, since, unless, while, where etc. Examples: She bought a shirt and a book.

Comment: Conjunctions are, however, not quite the same thing as logical operators, and the OP is interested in the latter. For example, *and* and *but* are different conjunctions, but the logical operator behind them is the same. *Or*, on the other hand, is notoriously ambiguous between two different logical operators.